# New Item inserted in Array but cannot reflect changes in return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I am adding items to the array. Items are added but not displayed the last item added. For example, array [1,2,3,4] prints 123 but does not display 4.

```
export default class App extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              input : [],
              Array:[],
            }
          }
        addTextInput = () => {
           this.state.Array.push(this.state.input.toString());
          }
          handleText=(text)=>{
            this.setState({input:text});
          }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
           
        <TextInput
       onChangeText={(text) =>this.handleText(text)}
      value={this.input} />
       <Button title='Add Item' onPress={() => this.addTextInput()} />
    {this.state.Array.map((item) => {
    <Text>{item}</Text>
    }
     </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to mutate the state directly in `addTextInput`, which is not allowed in React. You must update the array via `setState`, which will then trigger a render, which will display the new value:

```
addTextInput = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({ Array: [...prevState.Array, this.state.input.toString())) });
}
```